# Has anyone else experienced keyboard errors with VS 2010?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2010

Here's the situation: I'll be coding away in VS 2010, when all of a sudden the keyboard starts acting flaky. The up/down arrows will stop working, cut and paste keys will stop working, etc. The only way to fix it is to exit out of the IDE and then restart it (which is a pain). This will happen several times a day.

I know the problem is in VS 2010 because I can tab out to other applications and the keyboard will still be functioning normally.

I'm wondering if anyone else ever experiences this, or if it is a problem on my machine only.

Extensions installed:

```
DevExpress Tools v 10.1.1
Enterprise Library v5 Configuration Editor
Telerik.CommonPackage
Telerik.Web.UI.VSPackage
Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools
WCF REST Service Template 40(CS)
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm glad to know I'm not alone ;-)

Thanks for the link to the Connect site. I added my vote to re-open this as a bug. I also ran Windows Update, in case there was a fix that I had missed somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - I've had the up/down arrow problem, and I know a number of others have had keyboard problems too. There's a number of issues on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/SearchResults.aspx?KeywordSearchIn=2&SearchQuery=%22keyboard%22&FeedbackType=1&Scope=0&SortOrder=15&TabView=0#&&PageIndex=2) for this but they are marked as Fixed.

I hear just closing the document (rather than the whole IDE) can clear some problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think something similar was happening to my coworker's machine after installing VS2010.

And (I think) he said it was something to do with the language on the Keyboard. Just try adding the Keyboard again.

> Control Panel (Category view) ==>
>   Clock, Language, and Region ==> Region
>   and Language> and clicked Keyboard and
>   Language tab==> Change keyboards..
>   button ==> Add